# Installing IDEA on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, java, ubuntu-11.10

I am trying to install IDEA on Ubuntu 11.10. First, I installed `openjdk-7-jdk`. Then I tried running the `idea.sh` file as instructed. However it complains:

```
ERROR: cannot start IntelliJ IDEA.
No JDK found to run IDEA. Please validate either IDEA_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME 
environment variable points to valid JDK installation.

Press Enter to continue.
```

Trying to `echo` these three variables prints an empty line to the screen. How (and to what values) do I set these variables and proceed with the installation? Thanks.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4667/where-to-declare-environment-variables

Comment: @bbaja42: Doesn't really help. I also need to know what these variables I should set to.

Comment: Well, error message is quite verbose. You have installed openjdk. Find it's installation folder, and set either of these 3 variables(IDEA_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME) to openjdk installation folder.

Comment: @bbaja42: It really doesn't seem as straightforward as that to me. Also there is a reason I put "Noob here" in my original question.

Comment: @bbaja42: See my comment below Low Flying Pelican's answer.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

It's recommended to use the bundled **JetBrains Runtime** on Linux to run IntelliJ IDEA. At the moment IntelliJ IDEA requires Java 8 to run on this platform. It's possible to switch to a system or some other Java version, please [check the FAQ](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879).

---

Original answer (obsolete):

It's recommended to use OpenJDK 1.7+ or Oracle JDK to run IntelliJ IDEA on Linux, OpenJDK 1.6 is strictly unsupported because of the known performance and visual issues.

Starting from IntelliJ IDEA 16, custom JRE is bundled with Linux distributions.

The tricky part is that Oracle JDK is no longer distributed via .deb packages and you can't just install it with apt-get or Ubuntu Software Center.

Their site is also confusing and you can easily download JRE instead of the JDK (which will not work as IntelliJ IDEA needs tools.jar that is missing from JRE package).

[Here is the correct URL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u29-download-513648.html) for the JDK downloads (version 1.6.0_29). From this URL download the appropriate **.bin** file, for example **jdk-6u29-linux-i586.bin** if you need 32-bit Java or **jdk-6u29-linux-x64.bin** for 64-bit version.

```
chmod +x jdk-6u29-linux-i586.bin
./jdk-6u29-linux-i586.bin
```

to install in the **current** directory.

Inside **bin/idea.sh** add the following on the second line:

```
export IDEA_JDK=/path/to/jdk1.6.0_29
```

Normally resides under `/usr/lib/jvm/<YOUR_JDK>`. Now IntelliJ IDEA should start fine under Oracle JDK 1.6.0_29. You can verify it in `Help` | `About`.

Comment: I partially agree with your statement as it perfectly rational to develop with proprietary Java on a Windows based Hostas an example. Then share to an Ubuntu guest to develop with 'open' Java if needed... (ignore this if you don't use VirtualBox).

Comment: I do not really get all that hysteric warnings about Idea on OpenJDK. I use OpenJDK and must note that all bugs that I have seen personally while running Idea on OpenJDK are perfectly reproducible on Sun JDK - I see no difference. There is also no noticeable degradation in performance (at least for projects I working on).

Comment: Not longer distributed on .deb files? What happened to write once run everywhere?

Comment: _8u25_ seems to be the current version but I'm not able to find the binary file anywhere

Comment: How up to date is this advice about OpenJDK not being explicitly supported?  [The help article I came from](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827547-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under) seems to imply that it's now supported in some capacity under Linux.

Comment: sadly my JAVA_HOME always seems to take precedence over IDEA_JDK - it always complains about Java 7 (which JAVA_HOME points to, for compiling a legacy project with Maven on the command line). I need different VMs for IntelliJ and the rest of my system.

Comment: This solution works perfectly. I would like to add, for other jetbrain products the JDK variable name changes (for Pycharm for example, its name PYCHARM_JDK).

Answer (score 3):

You can set `JAVA_HOME` variable and add to your `PATH`, by doing the following.  As root open up `/etc/bash.bashrc` and add the following to the end of the file.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java
export JAVA_HOME
```

When you reboot, try running the following:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: Note that `PATH` is completely unrelated and there is _no_ need to reboot -- just start a new shell. Setting the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable in the system-wide `/etc/bash.bashrc` is also a bit of a blunt hammer -- perhaps another user on the system might want to use a different JRE.

Comment: I did as you sad. `echo $JAVA_HOME` works now. However trying to run `idea.sh` still fails with the same error.

Comment: Is it the correct path referring to the JAVA_HOME? (where you have installed openjdk?)

Comment: @missingfaktor . For debugging: Could you give output of ls "$JAVA_HOME". Also, edit idea.sh and add -x at first line, which will printout result of each operation on console. Show us that output as well.

Comment: @bbaja42: `echo $JAVA_HOME` prints `/usr/bin/java`.

Comment: @missingfaktor OK. That means that JAVA_HOME destination is incorrect. It should point to java installation folder, I can only guess where it is installed on your machine. Have you tried pelicans try, 'usr/lib/jvm/java'*

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5583/discussion-between-bbaja42-and-missingfaktor)

Comment: @bbaja42: Sorry for the delay, online on the chat now.

Comment: @Low Flying Pelican It is NOT recommended to edit bash.bashrc according to Ubuntu help page. User is advised to edit the /etc/environment file. If they would like updated shell/terminal without restart then they can use the source command:$ source /etc/environment

Answer (score 3):

I have had this problem a few times...

1. Add the IDEA_HOME/bin to your PATH
   Make sure JAVA_HOME & other variables are correct.

then run it from the terminal:

```
$ idea projects-name;
```

OR 2: navigate into the IDEA_HOME/bin and run it from there.

Answer (score 3):

i also face a question... in firs day all works without problems, but then...
i solve a problem: add to file `idea.sh` line with path to JDK `IDEA_JDK="/opt/java/32/jdk1.6.0_45/"`

add after 46 line

Answer (score 2):

If you had installed java, try:

```
type java
```

if you see like this:

```
java is /usr/java/default/java
```

then you should edit `.bash_profile`, add:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
```

then execute:

```
source .bash_profile
```

if you did not install java, you should install manual or auto.

Comment: @missingfaktor its a standard unix file which should be in your home directory and it must start with a `.`  Personally I prefer to add this to `/etc/profile.d` if you have access to `root`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can configure the JAVA_HOME in bash. But, IDEA use javac and java from standard bin folders. So, you have to configure like this.

- Download the JDK to home(~) folder
- extract the zip file
- use these command to mv to jvm folder under /usr/lib/jvm

  ```
  sudo mv -r ~/jdk-xx-version /usr/lib/jvm
  ```
- use these commands to configure the JAVA_HOME

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-xx-version/bin/java" 1 
  sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-xx-version/bin/javac" 1 
  sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-xx-version/bin/javaws" 1
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You install JDK 8 with:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Then, sometimes the problem lies on the default version of JAVA you are running. For this, use `update-alternatives` to modify it:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

See how I did it:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1069      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode
```

And now Intellij IDEA 2016.3 is running fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bash script for developers that installs IDEA so that you can run it from the shell via `idea.sh`

It also:

- Tests if the operating system is running on VirtualBox
- If it runs on VirtualBox, tests if IdeaProjects is set up for sharing
- If yes, writes a mount command to the bootstrap script to automount projects from host to guest
- Also creates a script to mount and unmount idea projects on-the-fly

```
#!/bin/bash
#Author: Yucca Nel http://thejarbar.org
#Modify these variables as needed...
tempWork=/tmp/work
defaultStartScript=/etc/init.d/rc.local
defaultIDEA=11.0.1
locBin=/usr/local/bin

read -p "Please [Enter] full path name of your local startup script ($defaultStartScript is the default). Please
make sure on this before providing a value by consulting documentation for your system:" locStartScript
locStartScript=${locStartScript:-$defaultStartScript}

read -p "Please [Enter] IDEA Version ($defaultIDEA is default):" ideaVersion
ideaVersion=${ideaVersion:-$defaultIDEA}


if [ ! -f $locStartScript ]
then
    echo "The file you provided could not be found. Remember to include the full path and try again. Exiting in 7 secs..."
    sleep 7
    exit 1
fi

mkdir -p /$tempWork
cd /$tempWork

sudo wget http://download-ln.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIC-$ideaVersion.tar.gz;
tar -zxvf ./*;

#Move it to a better location...
mv ./idea-IC-* $HOME/;

sudo ln -f -s $HOME/idea-*/bin/* /usr/bin/;

#If you use VirtualBox , you can share your projects between Host and guest. Name of shared
#folder must match 'IdeaProjects'
mkdir -p $HOME/IdeaProjects

if [ -f /sbin/mount.vboxsf ]
then
    sudo /sbin/umount $HOME/IdeaProjects
    sudo /sbin/mount.vboxsf IdeaProjects $HOME/IdeaProjects
fi

if mountpoint -q ~/IdeaProjects
then
#Add it to the start script to automate process...
if ! grep "sudo /sbin/mount.vboxsf IdeaProjects $HOME/IdeaProjects" $locStartScript
then
    echo "sudo /sbin/mount.vboxsf IdeaProjects $HOME/IdeaProjects" | sudo tee -a $locStartScript
fi
    sudo chmod +x $locStartScript

#Create a mount and unmount script file...
    rm -rf $tempWork/*
    echo '#!/bin/bash' > $tempWork/idea-mount.sh
    echo "sudo /sbin/mount.vboxsf IdeaProjects $HOME/IdeaProjects" >> $tempWork/idea-mount.sh
    echo "echo 'mounted IdeaProjects'" >> $tempWork/idea-mount.sh
    echo "exit 0" >> $tempWork/idea-mount.sh

    echo '#!/bin/bash' > $tempWork/idea-umount.sh
    echo "sudo umount $HOME/IdeaProjects" >> $tempWork/idea-umount.sh
    echo "echo 'unmounted IdeaProjects'" >> $tempWork/idea-mount.sh
    echo 'exit 0' >> $tempWork/idea-umount.sh

#Script for mounting ALL VirtualBox shared solders....
#If there isn't one create one...
if [ ! -f $locBin/mount-all-from-host.sh ]
then
    echo '#!/bin/bash' > $tempWork/mount-all-from-host.sh
    echo "sudo /sbin/mount.vboxsf IdeaProjects $HOME/IdeaProjects" | sudo tee -a $tempWork/mount-all-from-host.sh
    echo "exit 0" | sudo tee -a $tempWork/mount-all-from-host.sh

#Otherwise if there is one, but no mount, add one...
elif ! grep "sudo /sbin/mount.vboxsf IdeaProjects" $locBin/mount-all-from-host.sh
then
    sudo sed -ie '$d' $locBin/mount-all-from-host.sh
    echo "sudo /sbin/mount.vboxsf IdeaProjects $HOME/IdeaProjects" | sudo tee -a $locBin/mount-all-from-host.sh
    echo "exit 0" | sudo tee -a $locBin/mount-all-from-host.sh
fi

#Script for unmounting ALL VirtualBox shared folders...
#If there isn't one create one...
if [ ! -f $locBin/umount-all-from-host.sh ]
then
    echo '#!/bin/bash' > $tempWork/umount-all-from-host.sh
    echo "sudo umount -a -t vboxsf" | sudo tee -a $tempWork/umount-all-from-host.sh
    echo "echo 'unmounted all VirtualBox shared folders'" | sudo tee -a $tempWork/umount-all-from-host.sh
    echo "exit 0" | sudo tee -a $tempWork/umount-all-from-host.sh
fi

    sudo chmod +x $tempWork/*
    sudo mv -f $tempWork/*.sh $locBin/
    rm -rf $tempWork
fi

sudo rm -rf $tempWork

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the root cause for the original question, but it is the top hit when searching for this error:

```
ERROR: cannot start IntelliJ IDEA.
No JDK found to run IDEA. Please validate either IDEA_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME 
environment variable points to valid JDK installation.
```

Short answer: **If you were upgrading IDEA and run into this error and are using JBRE (JetBrains Runtime)**, export your previous runtime path to `JAVA_HOME` to load up the latest version of IDEA and allow the import wizard to copy configs over.

- The issue appears on my development environment when there's no default `JAVA_HOME` installed.
- I updated from `2019.2` to `2019.3`, which causes the latest version of IDEA to temporarily have no config files.
- This would mean there would be no 'valid Java runtime'.

**Solution**

1. Look into your previous configuration and lookup what runtime you're using:

`% cat ~/.IntelliJIdea2019.2/config/idea.jdk
/home/username/.IntelliJIdea2019.2/config/jdks/jbrsdk-8u232-linux-x64-b1638.3`

2. In my case above it is `jbrsdk-8u232-linux-x64-b1638.3` and the path is as shown above. **Export that temporarily as** `JAVA_HOME`.

`EXPORT JAVA_HOME=/home/username/.IntelliJIdea2019.2/config/jdks/jbrsdk-8u232-linux-x64-b1638.3`

3. Run `idea &`.

You should now have the first time run dialog show up to copy the config over, and you won't need to export the variable again.

Answer (score 0):

the solution arch linux takes with intellij idea 2020 is here:
https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/tree/trunk?h=packages/intellij-idea-community-edition

```
if [ -z "$IDEA_JDK" ] ; then
  IDEA_JDK="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/"
fi
# open-jfx location that should match the JDK version
if [ -z "$IDEA_JFX" ] ; then
  IDEA_JFX="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjfx/"
fi
# classpath according to defined JDK/JFX
if [ -z "$IDEA_CLASSPATH" ] ; then
  IDEA_CLASSPATH="${IDEA_JDK}/lib/*:${IDEA_JFX}/lib/*"
fi

exec env IDEA_JDK="$IDEA_JDK" IDEA_CLASSPATH="$IDEA_CLASSPATH" /usr/share/idea/bin/idea.sh "$@"
```