# OpenJDK or Sun Java for IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing IDEA on Ubuntu 11.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382641/installing-idea-on-ubuntu-11-10)

I have running IntelliJ IDEA with OpenJDK but at startup IntelliJ IDEA from terminal it shows me:

```
$ ./idea.sh 
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b24~pre2-1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
WARNING: You are launching IDE using OpenJDK Java runtime.

 THIS IS STRICTLY UNSUPPORTED DUE TO KNOWN PERFORMANCE AND GRAPHICS PROBLEMS!

 NOTE:    If you have both Oracle (Sun) JDK and OpenJDK installed
          please validate either IDEA_JDK, JDK_HOME, or JAVA_HOME environment          variable points to valid Oracle (Sun) JDK installation.
          See http://ow.ly/6TuKQ for more info on switching default JDK

 Press Enter to continue.
```

I have runing intelliJ IDEA because it requires "tools.jar", then I have that file on:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/lib
```

but "tools.jar" isn't over:
   /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26

So, my question is: someone had problems using OpenJDK?

Answer (score 3):

I had problems with IntelliJ IDEA 11 and OpenJDK  6. When compiling it thrown the next error:

```
Error: *.class (No such file or directory)
```

Switching to OpenJDK 7 solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can get full Oracle JDK with tools.jar on your Linux as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8384111/104891).

You can use OpenJDK on your own risk, but JetBrains will not accept support requests when you are running on it since the problems you want to report could be specific to this JDK.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move from OpenJDK to OracleJDK because of compatibility and performance issues.
Have a look to this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7) to install Oracle JDK7 if you use Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry, that is not right. OpenJDK is the upstream, it will have all the newest things, including bug fix.