# Intellij IDEA 12 slow response

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've upgraded to IDEA 12 and become frustrated with the slow response. Class navigation takes several seconds to populate the search list (previously it was instantly), any dialog relevant to file list operation hangs for minutes. Move a class to another package just hang up and I have to kill the process. Does anyone have the same experience with me?

**Additional information**:

- I am on windows 7
- I tried both 64 and 32 versions and both have the same issue
- My 64bit vmoption file has the following configuration:

[image]

- I have the log dir zipped and put on http://ge.tt/1JwgAnU/v/0. When I start to generating the log dir, I clean it first and then start IDEA 64 bits, open a project (automatically), then invoke File > import module command. I observed there are around a minutes delay before the dialog popped up. And inside the log dir I see a `threadDumps-20130106-091041-IU-123.100` folder. However there is no exception found in the idea.log file.

**Updates**

A screenr showing IDEA hang up when trying to move one class to another package by drag and drop: http://www.screenr.com/zlA7

Comment: I don't; I've found several significant speed improvements, and that's even before upping the JVM memory-related params. Nothing has hung at all. All this aside, you provide zero information that can actually be used to diagnose (OS, JDK, mem params, etc.)

Comment: Make sure that you have sufficient memory allocated to IDEA. Bottom right; you can see if you have un-used ram still available for idea.

Comment: I have attached additional information including the vmoptions. I suppose it should be more than enough for the memory allocation

Comment: The thread dumps in the logs directory show that filesystem access is taking an unusually long time on your machine. Do you have any mapped network drives? Do you have an antivirus running?

Comment: I have the same issue since IDEA v12. First it works fine but usually after 10-15 minutes it's getting slower and slower like a bad memory leak or something but there it still a lot of free memory (at least that's what IntelliJ tells me in the lower right corner).

v11.1 ist still running fine and a lot faster!?

I am using the 64-bit version on windows 7-x64 with the Oracle JDK 7 x64. 
my vmoptions:
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false

Comment: Uninstall the Floppy Drive Controller from the Device Manager. This worked for me on a Windows 8 system.

Comment: btw this also happens on linux systems

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the problem is caused by JDK 8 ea installed in my windows 7. IDEA use exe4j to load JDK, which automatically picked up JDK 8 (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188179/how-jetbrain-intellij-idea-select-java-to-bootup)).

After I defined `IDEA_JDK_64` environment variable and point that to my JDK 6, a high performance IDEA comes back!

Comment: thanks, that fixed the problem for me, too. I only had the IDEA_JDK variable defined and I thought the 64-bit IDEA version would use it.

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same, but solved it by changing a setting the idea64exe.vmoptions:
from...
`-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m`
...to...
`-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m`

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem with RubyMine (uses the same codebase) and it was because my system had swiched to OpenJDK instead of Sun/Oracle JDK.

I see that someone had similar problems in this thread: [OpenJDK or Sun Java for IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673163/openjdk-or-sun-java-for-intellij-idea)

Specifically, do you see something like the following when you start your IDE from the terminal?

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b24~pre2-1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
WARNING: You are launching IDE using OpenJDK Java runtime.

 THIS IS STRICTLY UNSUPPORTED DUE TO KNOWN PERFORMANCE AND GRAPHICS PROBLEMS!

 NOTE:    If you have both Oracle (Sun) JDK and OpenJDK installed
          please validate either IDEA_JDK, JDK_HOME, or JAVA_HOME environment          variable points to valid Oracle (Sun) JDK installation.
          See http://ow.ly/6TuKQ for more info on switching default JDK

 Press Enter to continue.
```

Perhaps you should check if the upgrade caused the IDE to revert to a non-Oracle JDK.

Comment: No I am using Oracle JDK on windows 7. I have tried both 64 and 32 bit JDK and they all have the same issue

Comment: On Arch Linux, installing aur/jdk and aur/jre6-compat gets rid of this message.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was a Findbugs plugin that caused frequent lags. You can see this if you run IDEA from the terminal and look at the log output, e.g.

> No classfiles specified; output will have no warnings

After disabling the real-time Findbugs scans (Settings -> Inspections -> Findbugs IDEA) everything ran smoothly again.

Comment: This fixed the problem in my IDE.. That's the big problem with third party plugins they sometimes screw things up. I try only to install plugins developed by jetbrains otherwise this is what happens