# How JetBrain IntelliJ IDEA select Java to bootup

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8

I have install Java 8 EA on my Window 7, but it's neither in my `%JAVA_HOME%` nor in the `%PATH%`. However when I start my IntelliJ IDEA v12 by clicking `idea64.exe`, it picked up java 8 EA instead of my  Java SDK 1.6.0_32, which is in the `%JAVA_HOME%` and `%PATH%`.

Anyone know when IDEA started, how it decide which Java version to run?

Comment: It relies on `IDEA_JDK`, have you tried setting this variable to the JDK you wanted?

Comment: I have not defined that environment variable

Comment: And if you define it, does that have the desired effect?

Comment: I've added the environment variable. it set the correct JDK if I launch from idea.bat, but still not good if it is launched from idea64.exe

Comment: In case you are opening Android Studio, you may use the `STUDIO_JDK` [environment variable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22956331/874502)

Answer (score 18):

It was picked from the registry.

When launched from .exe IDEA looks for Java in a following order:

1. IDEA_JDK (or IDEA_JDK_64) environment variable
2. jre/ (or jre64/) directory in IDEA home
3. registry
4. JDK_HOME environment variable
5. JAVA_HOME environment variable

When launched from .bat the order is same but registry isn't looked, and 64-suffixed vars aren't used (what is probably a bug).

Comment: which registry item? I have located JetBrain in both `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/software` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/software`, none of them presented a JDK option. `JavaSoft` key neither have something useful

Comment: Sorry, don't have a ready answer. IDEA uses exe4j for this. There are HKCU\Software\ej-technologies and HKLM\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft keys which may be relevant.

Comment: Still not there. Here is my HKCU/Software/ej-technologies: http://ge.tt/8vVkmvU/v/0. And there is no Wow6432Node at HKLM or HKLM/Software at all, neither does ej-technologies found under HKLM or HKLM/Software

Comment: What do you mean "not there"? Clearly there is Java 8 in a list of JVMs known to exe4j. If you don't want it to be picked either drop all it's mentions from registry, or override it with IDEA_JDK_64 env var.

Comment: Yes java 8 is in the list. The question is why exe4j choose it instead of anyone else in the same list? I don't have IDEA_JDK_64 defined. So how exe4j choose it?

Comment: Because it's version number is biggest.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I must say though that the 64bit Idea11 uses IDEA_JDK and not the IDEA_JDK_64 variable.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the available options that you can use for all the different operating systems. If you are interested.

http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under

Comment: The linked page no longer exists. It would have been better to put the relevant information directly into your answer instead of linking to it.

Comment: It's all there Mark you just have to log in first. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under?flash_digest=467bccd8b0182e4073a4062ed981c3723176ea9c

Comment: Also I do take your point Mark. Much easier to never leave SO but unfortunately it's quite a long article for all the different operating systems and options

Comment: Nope, I'm logged in, it still takes me to "the page you were looking for doesn't exist"

Comment: On further inspection, I think you had some sort of session token or user ID in the URL, removing that made this URL work for me: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under

Comment: This link no longer exists.

Comment: i came up saying it didnt work for me too but then it redirected me here https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional environment variable called IDEA_JDK to target the specific JDK that you want Intellij to use.

Comment: I've added the environment variable. it set the correct JDK if I launch from idea.bat, but still not good if it is launched from idea64.exe