# Error Launching IDEA (Intellij)

Tags: intellij-idea, java-9

When i've restarted my computer, i've tried to open Intellij and i've got this error message : 
**`failed to create jvm error code -1`**
[image: Screenshot]
[image]

i've added "***IDEA_JDK_64***" and still have the issue, i can't start intellij, can someone Help Please
**(NB : it's working with Eclipse actually )**

Comment: Is that not an incorrect path to home?

Comment: Nope, it's the right path, it's working with eclipse actually

Comment: Note that the recommended and officially supported JDK version is 1.8. I would recommend you to [use it for IDE to run](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879).

Comment: i've tried with the jdk 1.8, still the same problem :(

Comment: hi steve! :) question - how are you starting intellij? via commandline or via a desktop icon or start menu or how?

Comment: hi :) via desktop icone

Answer (score 0):

I've searched and I've found this. Try to define `JDK_HOME`:

[Setting JAVA_HOME for intelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379117/setting-java-home-for-intellij/17379262)

Comment: Have you tried with other sdk versions? I had the same problem with Netbeans a time ago, I reinstalled Java and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

May you set the `-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize` property more than `2048m`. Is this property higher than `2048m` you get your error message.