# Android Studio - OpenJDK 1.8 Vs Oracle JDK

Tags: android, android-studio, java

Android studio used to complaint about using OpenJDK and was recommending Oracle JDK. However with latest Android Studio, that prompt has gone (probably due to the legal dispute between both the companies).

I today installed Oracle JDK 1.8.0.92 and Android Studio 2.1.1 seems to be running faster, a noticeably faster.

Any idea what's the current status of Android studio with respect to Java 1.8 and also with respect to OpenJDK vs Oracle JDK.

Thanks

Comment: few QA's  https://jaxenter.com/java-8-will-be-introduced-to-android-by-changing-to-openjdk-123810.html

Comment: I assume that the source of the OpenJDK warning is not AndroidStudio but the underlaying IntelliJ IDE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673163/openjdk-or-sun-java-for-intellij-idea

Answer (score 3):

There is one main advantage of openJDK, and that is you can add ALPN jar into bootclasspath which is currently not supported by OrcaleJDK.

ALPN is basically used for http2 protocol when communicating with an http2 enabled Server. 
In android that can be used with a library like [okhttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Building).