# ERROR: cannot start RubyMine. No JDK found.  JDK Version? + desktop link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, java, ubuntu-11.04, rubymine

ERROR: cannot start RubyMine.
No JDK found. Please validate either RUBYMINE_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation.

I'm not sure what JDK version number to use to download it?

Also how to create a desktop link in 11.10?

Comment: `echo $RUBYMINE_JDK $JDK_HOME $JAVA_HOME`

Comment: `echo $RUBYMINE_JDK $JDK_HOME $JAVA_HOME

me@me:~$`  i.e. blank.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8384111/104891.

Comment: Use the latest possible.

Comment: I tried both 6 and 7 versions and seemed to be able to install at least the 6 version but I still get "No JDK found'.

Comment: Did you define environment variable in your `.bashrc` or in `rubymine.sh`? Can you show how it's defined?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turned out that in the end I had to do several things to get java running and thus resolve the issue:

### Get Java

Download oracle7 jdk at:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-jdk-7-download-432154.html
e.g. http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7/jdk-7-linux-x64.tar.gz

Follow instructions at:
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-jdk-in.html
e.g.

After downloading java (above):
Extract the downloaded Oracle Java JDK archive into your home folder and rename the newly created folder to "java-7-oracle".

```
sudo mv its_name java-7-oracle
```

---

### Install Java

```
cd
sudo mkdir -p  /usr/lib/jvm/ #just in case
sudo mv java-7-oracle/ /usr/lib/jvm/
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install update-java
sudo update-java  # choose version 1.7 if necessary.
```

---

### Check the Java install

```
java -version
javac -version
```

I was then able to start up rubyMine successfully.

---

### Create rubyMine shortcut

To create the desktop launcher in Ubuntu 11.10:

Once you've installed rubymine and you have the executable somewhere:

If it's called mine, then create a desktop launcher that runs it
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-create-desktop-launchers-in-ubuntu-11-10oneiric.html

You'll run (in a terminal window):

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new
```

Indicate where the rubyMine executable is, e.g. use `/usr/local/bin/mine` as the command to run.

You can then also drag that to the left side toolbar icons area for a icon quick-launcher there.

Note:
If following these instructions and making a quick-launch icon at the end - make sure NOT to delete the desktop icon you created earlier when cleaning up your desktop as this will also remove that quick-launch item (it's a link to it).

Answer (score 21):

I think using apt-get is easier, see for example [this article](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-install-java-jdk-on-ubuntu-linux):

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. It worked for me and it's quite easy!

Comment: Thank you. Worked for me  Ubuntu 14.04