# RubyMine on linux

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails-3, ide, intellij-idea

I am new in ubuntu and have a problem. I can not start RubyMine 4:

```
kvet@Kvet-Notebook:~/RubyMine-4.0.3/bin$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_03"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.1.1pre) (7~u3-2.1.1~pre1-1ubuntu2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)
kvet@Kvet-Notebook:~/RubyMine-4.0.3/bin$ ./rubymine.sh
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.1.1pre) (7~u3-2.1.1~pre1-1ubuntu2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)
WARNING: You are launching the IDE using OpenJDK Java runtime.

         THIS IS STRICTLY UNSUPPORTED DUE TO KNOWN PERFORMANCE AND GRAPHICS PROBLEMS!

NOTE:    If you have both Oracle (Sun) JDK and OpenJDK installed
         please validate either RUBYMINE_JDK, JDK_HOME, or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid Oracle (Sun) JDK installation.
         See http://ow.ly/6TuKQ for more info on switching default JDK.

Press Enter to continue.

Error: Could not find or load main class com.intellij.idea.Main
```

I tried to install openjdk6 and has same error. I dont know what I must do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had this recently myself ([[ERROR: cannot start RubyMine. No JDK found.  JDK Version? + desktop link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862143/error-cannot-start-rubymine-no-jdk-found-jdk-version-desktop-link][1])).

> Answer: Install java and check your path:

**Download oracle7 jdk at:**
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-jdk-7-download-432154.html

**Follow instructions at:**
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-jdk-in.html e.g.

After downloading java (above): Extract the downloaded Oracle Java JDK archive into your home folder and rename the newly created folder to "java-7-oracle".

```
sudo mv its_name java-7-oracle
```

**Install it:**

```
cd
sudo mkdir -p  /usr/lib/jvm/ #just in case
sudo mv java-7-oracle/ /usr/lib/jvm/
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install update-java
sudo update-java
```

**Check it:**

```
java -version
javac -version
```

Comment: launcher no longer wrote about open jdk, but still print this:
kvet@Kvet-Notebook:~/RubyMine-4.0.3/bin$ ./rubymine.sh
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)
Error: Could not find or load main class com.intellij.idea.Main

Comment: That did not help me (it just get rid of the OpenJDK-Warning). Reinstalling (means & tar xfz RubyMine-4.0.3.tar.gz $ cd RubyMine-4.0.3/bin/ $ ./rubymine.sh) did the trick for me (don't know why).

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you don't need to install JDK. For RubyMine to run, all you need is JRE. Unless you are going to do Java development, you don't need JDK.

To setup Oracle / Sun JRE on Ubuntu / Mint / Debian, follow the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java#Oracle_Java_7 .

Personally, I have used the instructions under `Script (JRE only)` section. Specifically, I installed JRE using the repository mentioned on this site: http://www.duinsoft.nl/packages.php?t=en . Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the Oracle JDK and running RubyMine with that.