# cannot run pycharm 2.5.1 on kubuntu inux

Tags: jar, sh, pycharm, ubuntu

I want to run pycharm 2.5.1 on kubuntu but i get this error

```
mohammad@mohammad-Inspiron-1564:/media/storage/Linux/pycharm-2.5.1/bin$ sh pycharm.sh 
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.1.1pre) (7~u3-2.1.1~pre1-1ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)
WARNING: You are launching the IDE using OpenJDK Java runtime.

         ITS KNOWN TO HAVE PERFORMANCE AND GRAPHICS ISSUES!
         SWITCH TO THE ORACLE(SUN) JDK BEFORE REPORTING PROBLEMS!

NOTE:    If you have both Oracle (Sun) JDK and OpenJDK installed
         please validate either PYCHARM_JDK, JDK_HOME, or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid Oracle (Sun) JDK installation.
         See http://ow.ly/6TuKQ for more info on switching default JDK.

Press Enter to continue.

Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/ClassNotFoundException: error in opening JAR file ../lib/boot.jar
```

before Kubuntu i have opensuse and ubuntu and I have no problem to run pycharm but i dont know why it occurs

---

Regards
Mohammad

Comment: Did you already try to install Oracle JDK? You can use this guide: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8384111/104891. The only difference is that you will edit/run `pycharm.sh` instead of `idea.sh`.

Comment: I have download oracle jdk now but i don't know how to install it

Comment: Please check the link in the previous comment for the installation instructions.

Comment: don't work
perhaps it is some problem in my kubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my java installed and some other packages
I have uninstall all java packages and its libraries and install again
then it works fine