# Ugly font and broken source code editor in Intellij 11.1.x after update to jdk 7u9

Tags: fonts, intellij-idea, java

After an update of java sdk on ubuntu 12.04 (openjdk7 to java oracle 7u9 : ), my Intellij installation is totally broken : Ugly font, code editor broken, etc.

Other program which use java works like a charm (netbeans run without problem, etc.)

```
java version "1.7.0_09" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
1.7.0_09-b05) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

All symbolic links to java, javac, etc are good.

I try to update to the latest build, whitout success.

Are you experienced the same problem recently ?

[image]

Updated with other color scheme :

[image]

Jdk version :

[image]

With font override option and scheme default activated, my font are UGLY and BIG :

[image]

And same configuration with jdk 7u1 :

[image]

Comment: Oracle JDK 1.6 is recommended (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8384111/104891), see also http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-57233 for the hints how to improve fonts.

Comment: OK, it's not exactly the same problem, when i change the java version in `/bin/idea.sh` by with the cmd `export IDEA_JDK=/path/to/jdk1.7`, the u1 work without any problem, so i think i can post a new bug report to intellij ?

Comment: Did you try to change **Look and Feel** to **GTK+**?

Comment: This is same problem with all, it's less ugly, but the source code editor don't work with other look and feel Information text are big.

Comment: No highlighting in the code editor is a different problem, you have `.scala` files mapped to `Text Files` in `Settings` | `File Types`. Make sure Scala plug-in is installed and enabled and `.scala` files are mapped to the `Scala Files` type.

Comment: Look and Feel font can be changed with **Override default fonts** option, select different font and change the size.

Comment: Yep for the color, it's ok, i re-install the scala plugin, it works.
For the rest of font, i try all of this (override,etc) with latest sdk: ok font are less ugly, but it's not perfect, and source code editor continue to bug :/ I use a custom color scheme, perhaps it's this,i try.

Comment: What JDK is displayed in `Help` | `About`? Does it happen with `GTK+` L&F?

Comment: Also note that fonts in Java Swing applications on Linux are never perfect, [see here why](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-57233).

Comment: I update with new screenshoot, it's really ugly :)

Comment: Please run under JDK 1.6 as recommended in my first comment, Editor font can be changed (change both font and size), see [this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-57233) for details what fonts and JVM options you can try to improve it.

Comment: Yes, it's correct, i post the same configuration for fonts (same size) and color scheme with jdk 1.7 so you can see the difference ! It's a really big difference :) I'm not sure it's exactly the same issue .. it not a simple problem of antialising :/ But the principal it's intellij work with the 7u1 :)

Comment: I've provided the answer with the summary of the present situation. Sorry that I can't be more helpful with this Java/Linux fonts issue. You are welcome to try different combination of Java versions, fonts and other options to see which one works best for you.

Comment: When the next version of java 1.7 is out, i test and get some feedback here probably :) Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Font rendering on Linux in Java Swing applications is not perfect and [we already have an open issue for this problem](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-57233) where you can find some hints how to tweak it (by using different fonts, by patching font files, by patching JDK, by supplying JVM options, etc).

Unfortunately, it's extremely hard to get exactly the same font rendering as in the other elements of the native system user interface.

Good news is that we have plans to implement native font rendering for the editor in the future IntelliJ IDEA versions (we'll be using system default freetype library directly for the best possible and consistent font appearance).

Comment: Any idea which version of IntelliJ you would be targeting that feature for? The preview of version 12 doesn't seem to have native rendering.

Comment: We don't have any estimates yet, sorry.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, are there any news regarding the case in ***IntelliJ Idea*** 14.1 or even 15.0, running on ***Oracle Java 8*** on ***Ubuntu*** / ***Ubuntu Gnome 15.04***?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem on Fedora 17 with IntelliJ 11.1.3 - java version "1.7.0_09". I had some "problematic" fonts installed on my system. It was enought to remove *tex-dejavu* fonts in */usr/share/fonts*. So it could be helpful look on fonts you are using in your system as CrazyCoder wrote.