# Cannot build actual Intellij IDEA community edition

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea

I am trying to follow [these steps](http://www.jetbrains.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=983225).

And I have a problem on "make project" step:

```
invalid inferred types for T,A; inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
inferred: java.lang.Object
bound(s): T
```

in ("return addAll(newHashSet(items));")

```
@NotNull
public static <T> Set<T> set(@NotNull T ... items) {
  return addAll(newHashSet(items));
}

@NotNull
public static <T, A extends T, C extends Collection<T>> C addAll(@NotNull C collection, @NotNull A... elements) {
  //noinspection ManualArrayToCollectionCopy
  for (T element : elements) {
    collection.add(element);
  }
  return collection;
}
```

It seems strange - the source code is actual and I think, it could be a problem in Project Configuration.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More info would be helpful. Like which java you are running? Your environment setting listed out.

Comment: openjdk-6. It seems to be a good idea to try another jdk package.

Comment: I would not use openjdk. :) That seems to me like a problem.

Comment: Oracle JDK would be recommended, if you are on Linux, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8384111/104891.