# Intellij IDEA: Unable to compile java code

Tags: intellij-idea

Whenever I try to compile/run a java code I get the following.

```
Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 2 sec
1 error
0 warnings
java: Cannot find JDK '1.6' for module 'balh'  <= ERROR
```

The SDK path is set and selected in "Project SDK"
I'm using IDEA 12 on RHEL 6.2

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure to [use Oracle JDK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8384111/104891), try to add a new JSDK configuration in IDEA and check that all modules/project has this new JDK selected, then rebuild the project. If you still have a problem, share a sample project illustrating this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your dependencies include Java 1.6 in that specific module.

[image: IntelliJ 11, showing module page with dependencies tab open.]

Here, my module SDK is Java 1.7, but it's the same idea - if Java 1.6 doesn't appear or isn't available, either use the project SDK or find it on your box using the "New" dialog.

Comment: I do have the Java 1.6 SDK set for the Module just like in your screenshot. Still have the same problem.

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm using Windows 8 64bit and have 1.7 JDK (64bit) installed. I've tried switching between 32bit JDK's and still nothing changes.