# Having to double click on Menu items in IntelliJ to execute desired functionality

Tags: intellij-idea

I have recently installed IntelliJ 12 and have noticed that I have to always do a double click to perform common operations like executing a menu command or closing a tab by clicking on 'X'. My team mates, however, don't face the same issue, so I'm inclined to believe that it is a configuration issue.

Has anyone faced this issue before? I have set the "Autoscroll from source" option that now opens files with one click. I still have to double-click on Menu items.

Comment: Which OS are you running?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: What window manager do you use? It may have some setting that affects menu behavior in Java applications, also make sure to [run under Oracle JDK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8384111/104891).

Comment: I was using Unity, but the issue persists when I switched to Gnome.