# I Can't copy code directly from IntelliJ Idea to StackOverflow

Tags: intellij-idea, copy, copy-paste, paste

I can't copy directly from IntelliJ Idea to Stack Overflow. It is really annoying to paste from Intellij to `.txt` to Stack.

How can I paste in civilized way?

Edit: My soft versions:

- Intellij Idea 12 ultimate
- Linux ubuntu 10

Comment: What are your OS and Java versions? Any intermidiate software (screen sharing, clipboard handling etc.)?

Comment: I have no intermidiate soft, regular intellij and ubuntu.

Comment: Which Java version is used to run IDEA? It can be seen on a Help | About screen, or in a Help | Reveal Log file.

Comment: This question probably belongs on META.

Comment: Make sure to [run under Oracle JDK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8384111/104891).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was using openJDK, switching to OracleJDK solves the problem.

Comment: I have java-7-oracle, and still I can't copy

Comment: Make sure that it is hardcoded into IntelliJ config file.

Comment: to tell you the truth, it's not that simple that it doesn't work. It works for some words, sometimes it works only for every second time I try to copy. It's REALLY strange...

Answer (score 0):

Why not?  Because it doesn't have 4 spaces in front of it?  What I do is paste the code in to this text area, highlight it, and then press the {} button to indent it for me.

So this

becomes

```
So this
```

Comment: It's not the problem that I have no indentation. I can't copy directly at all.

Comment: It works fine for me.  I don't think I can help because I can't reproduce it.  What OS are you using?  What version of intellij?  Can you copy/paste between other parts of intellij?

Comment: I can copy paste between different parts of intellij.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I have not installed svn command line client. And it always popup a dialog box telling me to fix the svn command line client.

After installed svn command line client, I can copy and paste codes normally.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many options, but switching to JDK 7 from 6 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with IntelliJ 16.2 .. 17.2:

- Copy in IntelliJ
- Paste elsewhere
- FAIL

However:

- Copy in IntelliJ
- **Paste in IntelliJ**
- Paste elsewhere
- WIN!