# pycharm install problematic in linux?

Tags: pycharm

./pycharm.sh 
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.8.13) (6b18-1.8.13-0+squeeze2)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)
WARNING: You are launching the IDE using OpenJDK Java runtime.

```
     ITS KNOWN TO HAVE PERFORMANCE AND GRAPHICS ISSUES!
     SWITCH TO THE ORACLE(SUN) JDK BEFORE REPORTING PROBLEMS!
```

NOTE:    If you have both Oracle (Sun) JDK and OpenJDK installed
         please validate either PYCHARM_JDK, JDK_HOME, or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid Oracle (Sun) JDK installation.
         See [ow.ly/6TuKQ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/system-requirements-and-installation.html?origin=old_help#h2linux) for more info on switching default JDK.

Press Enter to continue.

Unrecognized VM option '+UseCodeCacheFlushing'
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

how to install pycharm i have sun jdk in 1.6.what will do?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/8384111/104891 for the instructions.

Comment: which distribution are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the instructions in the message you have pasted and define the PYCHARM_JDK environment variable pointing to your Sun JDK 1.6 installation.