# What would cause Intellij to suddenly get really slow with scala?

Tags: performance, scala, playframework, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I have been using Intellij 12 to build a Play Framework 2 app for about a month.  It's been fine up until yesterday.  Now when ever I try to write code in one of the scala templates Intellij gets very very very slow.  Like it takes 5-10 seconds to enter a couple new lines.  What would cause this to start happening all of a sudden and how do I fix it?

I tried increasing my vm options to the following, but it didn't help:

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx800m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Edit: Could a recent Intellij or plugin update have destroyed performance?

Edit: I updated my Scala and Play plugins and it didn't help.

Comment: I also notice this hell slowly. :(

Comment: Report at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/SCL with a [CPU snapshot](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-192). Make sure to run under [Oracle JDK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8384111/104891) and check that you don't have EclipseMod plug-in installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI..

Try to update to new version (0.2.16)

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin?pluginId=7080

Comment: This worked after much messing around.  I had to manually instal it because it wasn't available through intellij, but then scala wasn't compatible.  I had to manually instal scala, but something didn't work and I had to remove scala.  Then downloaded scala from scratch inside Intellij.  Works now.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, switching to sun java from openjdk fixed it. Also check if it isn't doing something in the background like indexing or sth like that. Just a guess. Cheers!

Edit: google-fu resulted in one potencionally interesting fact. A lot of scala users are experiencing this. It looks that scala is only available in intellij 12 and this is a first version, so it's probably a problem on the side of scala devs.. if I manage to find a workaround I'll post it here. Brace for scala updates until then ;)

Comment: I'm running OSX 10.8.  Doesn't that use sun java by default?

Comment: Dunno, never had OSX, open the console/ command prompt and you can check it by executing the "java -v" or "java -version" command. But it looks like a scala problem as I mentioned..

Comment: Ok.  It doesn't say anything about sun.  Its just this: java version "1.7.0_09"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: That's OK, you got the right one. Problem is in Scala as I mentioned in the answer. Try to update it when a patch comes out.. Hope it gets fixed soon ;)