# Webstorm desktop launcher

Tags: java, linux, bash, path, webstorm

I'm trying to get a working desktop launcher for Webstorm (applicable to any JetBrains product, however.) I've tried using the built-in menu "Add desktop launcher" in both Xubuntu and Lubuntu with no dice.

Running ./webstorm.sh from a terminal in the application's folder works fine.

If I add the option to the .desktop file to run in terminal I get an error message:

> ERROR: cannot start WebStorm.
>   No JDK found. Please validate either WEBIDE_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable >points to valid JDK installation.
>
> Press Enter to continue.

If I open a terminal and do javac -version I get a response, indicating my path is set correctly.

What gives? I am baffled as to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Terminal environment != desktop environment. As a workaround you can define `JAVA_HOME` [directly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8384111/104891) in `webstorm.sh`.

Answer (score 3):

Set `JAVA_HOME` in your `~/.profile` like this:

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/
```

Then restart your system (or just X-Windows using `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart`).