# PhpStorm cannot start from start menu on ubunt 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm

I have installed PhpStorm6 on ubuntu 12.04LTS,the phpStorm need jdk to start,so I install jdk7 on /usr/local/environment/jdk7 and successfully start the phpStorm with script phpstorm.sh.
 but after i use phpstorm  command(tool/create desktop entry) to add this ide to Ubnut start menu,i cannot start it from start menu ,the error reported is:No JDK found.

I have export JAVA_HOME JRE_HMEO CLASS_PATH on ~/.bashrc,and have change default sh from dash to bash(sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash ),it seems that the environment variable is not export,how coulid i fixde the issue?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8384111/104891). You can specify `JDK_HOME` directly in the `.sh` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the java links via update-alternatives to your custom installation. Or grab a packaged java7 and install that.