# Unrecognized vm option when opening RubyMine on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, rubymine

New to RubyMine. I am trying to open RubyMine on Ubuntu and getting following error -

$ bin/rubymine.sh

Unrecognized VM option '+UseCodeCacheFlushing' 
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

**My java version is** -

$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_10"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_10-b33)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 11.0-b15, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 2):

You should [update JDK to a more recent version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8384111/104891), the one you have installed is too old and doesn't support `+UseCodeCacheFlushing` option

Answer (score 0):

After some R&D. This is how i resolved this problem.

I open the **rubymine.vmoptions** file in edit mode

$ RubyMine-5.4.3.2.1$ sudo nano rubymine.vmoptions

I found following entries in the file-

-Xms128m 
  -Xmx512m 
  -XX:MaxPermSize=1000m

-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m 
  -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing 
  -ea 
  -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false 
  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

I increased the memory size in first 3 entries and remove some entries from the file. These are the final entries in my file -

-Xms800m 
  -Xmx1200m 
  -XX:MaxPermSize=1000m 
  -ea

Now when i executed 
  $ bin/rubymine.sh

It open the RubyMine editor. I am not sure is this the correct solution, but it work for me :)

Comment: You should [update JDK to a more recent version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8384111/104891), the one you have installed is too old and doesn't support `+UseCodeCacheFlushing` option.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Could you make that an answer?

Comment: I had the same problem with pycharm and I removed -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing line from pycharm64.vmoptions file.
It worked for me.