# IntelliJ can't find tools.jar without sudo

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run IntelliJ on Ubuntu 14.04. I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382641/installing-idea-on-ubuntu-11-10/8384111#8384111) but the solutions don't apply -- I've definitely got the JDK installed rather than the JRE. When I try to run `idea.sh`, I get the error message:

> 'tools.jar' seems to be not in IDEA classpath. Please ensure JAVA_HOME
>   points to JDK rather than JRE.

`JAVA_HOME` is set to `/etc/java-7-openjdk`. Eclipse (in the form of Eclim) has no problem finding it. `javac -version` prints `javac 1.7.0_55`.

However, if I run `sudo ./idea.sh`, IntellJ launches fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out `JAVA_HOME` was set wrong, I needed to set it to:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

to get it working. I'm not sure why this hadn't caused me any problems before.

EDIT: This setting makes Maven angry (although Maven via IntelliJ works fine). For future readers, I believe the correct setting is:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same problem half an hour ago. Took me exactly that half hour to fix it, this is how it worked for me:

**Short version:**
add

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

to your `.bashrc`, source it and you are fine.

**Explanation:**

After installing the JDK in Ubuntu there are multiple folders on your disk.
The root folder is

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
```

under which the aforementioned `/jre` -Folder resides.
The whole problem is, that the `jre/lib` -Folder does not contain the `tools.jar` - File searched by the IDE.
Only the `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib` - Folder does.

To get everything working you have to specify `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64` as `JAVA_HOME`.

Setting `/usr` as your `JAVA_HOME` wont solve the problem as that is symlinked to `/etc/alternatives` which is symlinked to our old friend the `/jre`-Folder.

I hope this helped you!

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly the issue I was facing and your solution/explanation helped me resolve it!

Comment: You know that "export" is not needed in `.bashrc` file? Thus can be removed.

Answer (score 3):

In the 64 bit Debian 7, I solved the problem by adding this two lines of code in idea.sh under the /path/to/intellij-folder/bin/

```
export IDEA_JDK=/path/to/jdk/
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jre
```

And I hope it will solve the problem in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your current java version as follows

```
alternatives --config java 
alternatives --config javac
```

but before them you need to install your newly installed JDK in alternatives properly:

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java [new-jdk-path]/bin/java 120 --slave /usr/bin/rmiregistry rmiregistery [new-jdk-path]/bin/rmiregistry --slave /usr/bin/keytool keytool [new-jdk-path]/bin/keytool --slave /usr/lib/tools.jar tools.jar [new-jdk-path]/lib/tools.jar

alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac [new-jdk-path]/bin/javac 120 --slave /usr/bin/jar jar [new-jdk-path]/bin/jar --slave /usr/bin/rmic rmic [new-jdk-path]/bin/rmic
```